# Half of screen is unclickable

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, ios7

I have a very perplexing problem. I have a `UIView` with a few buttons spread across it. For whatever reason when you rotate the view(simulator or device) the buttons on the right half of the screen become unclickable. The unclickable area resembles the size of the orientation that was just rotated from. For example, if you have an iPhone in portrait mode and turn it to landscape the unclickable area is about the width of the iPhone screen in portrait. At first I thought that their must be an invisible element on top of that portion of the screen that was intercepting the clicks, but then I set the alpha of everything on screen to 1 and set every elements border color (via `CALayer`) so I could inspect. Surprisingly everything was where it was supposed to be and their was nothing(that I could find) covering the buttons. I even tried bringing the buttons to the front via `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.BUTTON]`

I have one function that handles setting the frames of everything when the view is either loaded or rotated. This function call is the ONLY thing in my rotation function and my `viewWillAppear` function. The unclickable buttons problem only happens when the device is rotated. For example, if you rotate the device from portrait to landscape and the buttons become unclickable, then all you have to do is select another tab from the tab bar at the bottom to load another view, then when you click back on the tab with the view with this weird problem(not having rotated anything), the buttons are all clickable and working as expected. The thing I just cant comprehend about this problem is that the EXACT same code is called in `viewWillAppear` and `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation` yet the buttons are only unclickable when the device is rotated and the buttons are clicked. If the user clicks on another tab and then returns the the tab with this problem, the buttons now work as expected.

To complicate things further, this problem ONLY occurs on ios7. Everything is all fine and dandy on ios6.

I have tried everything I can think of and I just don't have a clue as to why this is happening.

Here is some of the code:

```
-(void)loadCorrectElements{

    if(self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){

        //portrait
        int amountToSubtract = ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)?20:0;
        int distanceBetweenLabels = (self.view.bounds.size.height - amountToSubtract) / 5;
        self.viewForLabels.frame = CGRectMake(0, distanceBetweenLabels, self.view.bounds.size.width, distanceBetweenLabels*3);

        int heightOfLabels = (self.viewForLabels.bounds.size.height / 3) - 20;
        int ycoordOfLongitudeLabel = (self.viewForLabels.bounds.size.height / 3) + 10;
        int ycoordOfAltitudeLabel = ((self.viewForLabels.bounds.size.height / 3) * 2) + 10;
        self.latitudeLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, self.view.bounds.size.width-20, heightOfLabels);
        self.longitudeLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, ycoordOfLongitudeLabel, self.view.bounds.size.width-20, heightOfLabels);
        self.altitudeLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, ycoordOfAltitudeLabel, self.view.bounds.size.width-20, heightOfLabels);

        self.optionsButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width-36, self.view.bounds.size.height-36, 26, 26);

        int ycoordForSpeakButton = self.viewForLabels.frame.origin.y + self.viewForLabels.frame.size.height + 10;
        self.speakButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width - 40, ycoordForSpeakButton, 30, 25);

        int heightOfRecordLabel = ((self.view.bounds.size.height - (self.viewForLabels.frame.origin.y + self.viewForLabels.frame.size.height))) / 2;
        int yCoordForRecordButton = self.viewForLabels.frame.origin.y + self.viewForLabels.frame.size.height + (((self.view.bounds.size.height - (self.viewForLabels.frame.origin.y + self.viewForLabels.frame.size.height)) / 2) - (heightOfRecordLabel / 2));
        self.recordButton.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.bounds.size.width / 2) - (self.view.bounds.size.width / 4) / 2, yCoordForRecordButton, self.view.bounds.size.width / 4, heightOfRecordLabel);

        int ycoordForOldCoordsButton = self.viewForLabels.frame.origin.y + self.viewForLabels.frame.size.height + (((self.view.bounds.size.height - (self.viewForLabels.frame.origin.y + self.viewForLabels.frame.size.height))) / 2 - 12);
        self.oldCoordsButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, ycoordForOldCoordsButton, 24, 24);
    }else{

        //landscape
        int amountToSubtract = ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)?20:0;
        self.viewForLabels.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5 + amountToSubtract, self.view.bounds.size.width-10, self.view.bounds.size.height - 60);

        int heightOfLabels = (self.viewForLabels.bounds.size.height - amountToSubtract) / 3;
        int ycoordOfLongitudeLabel = (self.viewForLabels.bounds.size.height / 3);
        int ycoordOfAltitudeLabel = ((self.viewForLabels.bounds.size.height / 3) * 2);

        self.latitudeLabel.frame = CGRectMake(5, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width-20, heightOfLabels);
        self.longitudeLabel.frame = CGRectMake(5, ycoordOfLongitudeLabel, self.view.bounds.size.width-20, heightOfLabels);
        self.altitudeLabel.frame = CGRectMake(5, ycoordOfAltitudeLabel, self.view.bounds.size.width-20, heightOfLabels);

        int yCoordForOptionsButton = self.viewForLabels.frame.origin.y + self.viewForLabels.frame.size.height + (((self.view.bounds.size.height - (self.viewForLabels.frame.origin.y + self.viewForLabels.frame.size.height)) / 2) - 13);
        self.optionsButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width - 31, yCoordForOptionsButton, 26, 26);

        self.speakButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.optionsButton.frame.origin.x - 40, self.optionsButton.frame.origin.y, 30, 25);

        int heightOfRecordLabel = ((self.view.bounds.size.height - (self.viewForLabels.frame.origin.y + self.viewForLabels.frame.size.height))) / 2;
        int yCoordForRecordButton = self.viewForLabels.frame.origin.y + self.viewForLabels.frame.size.height + (((self.view.bounds.size.height - (self.viewForLabels.frame.origin.y + self.viewForLabels.frame.size.height)) / 2) - (heightOfRecordLabel / 2));
        self.recordButton.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.bounds.size.width / 2) - (self.view.bounds.size.width / 4) / 2, yCoordForRecordButton, self.view.bounds.size.width / 4, heightOfRecordLabel);
        int ycoordForOldCoordsButton = self.viewForLabels.frame.origin.y + self.viewForLabels.frame.size.height + (((self.view.bounds.size.height - (self.viewForLabels.frame.origin.y + self.viewForLabels.frame.size.height))) / 2 - 12);
        self.oldCoordsButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, ycoordForOldCoordsButton, 24, 24);

    }//end if

    [self setLabelText:self.latitudeLabel text:self.latitudeLabel.text];
    [self setLabelText:self.longitudeLabel text:self.longitudeLabel.text];
    [self setLabelText:self.altitudeLabel text:self.altitudeLabel.text];

    self.mainContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);

}//end method

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self loadCorrectElements];
}//end function

-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{
    [self loadCorrectElements];
}//end function
```

Here are the button declarations inside ViewDidLoad

```
 //create options button
        self.optionsButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [self.optionsButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Share.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.optionsButton addTarget:self action:@selector(shareButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.mainContainer addSubview:self.optionsButton];

        //create speak button
        self.speakButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [self.speakButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Sound.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.speakButton addTarget:self action:@selector(speakButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.mainContainer addSubview:self.speakButton];

        //create record button
        self.recordButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        self.recordButton.backgroundColor = self.blueColor;
        [self.recordButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"RECORD", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.recordButton.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0f;
        [self.recordButton addTarget:self action:@selector(recordButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.recordButton setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [self.mainContainer addSubview:self.recordButton];

        //set up old coord button
        self.oldCoordsButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [self.oldCoordsButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Clock.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.oldCoordsButton addTarget:self action:@selector(oldCoordsButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.mainContainer addSubview:self.oldCoordsButton];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the viewController's view or the mainWindow is not resizing on rotation.

As Jesse Rusak mentions in his answer, it really makes no sense to do so much calculations in your code to setup the buttons to handle rotation.

Use AutoResizingMasks. It can take out a zillion lines of code. Once you have mastered it, you can move to Auto Layout.

your autoresizing masks can be set somewhat like this

```
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | 
                             UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight |  
                             UIViewAutoresizingFixedBottomMargin |
                             UIViewAutoresizingFixedLeftMargin |        
                             UIViewAutoresizingFixedRightMargin | 
                             UIViewAutoresizingFixedTopMargin;
```

similarly, you can set the autoresizing masks for the buttons. And it'll take care of positioning on rotation. Try a few different options, you'll get the hang of it soon.

Answer (score 2):

It seems likely to me that a superview of your buttons is not being resized correctly. (Views can still be visible outside of their superview, but they won't be interactive.)

I would suggest using a tool like [Reveal](http://revealapp.com/) or [Spark Inspector](http://sparkinspector.com/) to see where your views are after rotation and so let you figure out which one isn't being resized correctly.

As an aside, you might want to look into using nibs and auto layout for your layouts in the future, as it would eliminate all of the above code.